# Inbound port configuration of Azure is not working

Tags: azure

I have a simple webserver running on Windows instance of Azure.All I want to access this application from browser from outside the VM.Internally by localhost I am able to access the application.But I am not able to access the application from the Internet.Also I checked via yougetsignal the port is not opened.What configuration am I missing here?

[image: Configuration Pic 1]

[image: Configuration Pic 2]

Comment: Just to be clear: You're trying to access your service on port 5555, from outside of Azure?

Comment: @DavidMakogon yes that is the correct understanding

Comment: Did you create an inbound rule for port 5555 in the Windows Firewall

Comment: @Francois I did what the two screenshots show. I didnnot create any rule in the firewall.How to do that?